# SQL find percentage of group?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have an SQL table with a column of names and a column of prices they paid for tickets. What query can I use to find the percentage of people who paid more than £100? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can use `avg()` to get the ratio:

```
select avg(case when price > 100 then 1.0 else 0 end)
from t;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select 
   100.0                                      -- to get a percentage
   * count(case when price > 100 then 1 end)  -- who paid over 100?
   / count(*)                                 -- all rows
from tickets
```